# Is there a way to delete directory content when close or exit a Django project?

Tags: python, django

I want to delete all content of a directory "/media/" at the moment that user closes or finishes a Django project, this means by closing browser tab, or closing browser itself.

I found this code to erase files ended in some extension, but I don't know how to use it and in which file of my project.

```
import os

filelist = [ f for f in os.listdir(mydir) if f.endswith(".bak") ]
for f in filelist:
os.remove(os.path.join(mydir, f))
```

Comment: There is no guaranteed method to know when a browser/tab is closing (the network could go down, the power could go down, the user could close their laptop and never open it again, etc, etc)

Comment: how do you know which files to delete? the /media/ directory is shared for all users, some of which might still be online...